# Prevent Modal Closing on form submit in Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to prevent the modal from closing when a form is submitted?

I am working on Email Sending Modal But When Click On Submit Button Controller Returns View, How To Prevent This ?

Modal Code Here:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form1", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
            <span class="btn green fileinput-button">
                <i class="fa fa-plus fa fa-white"></i>
                <span >Attachment</span>
                <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files" id="file">
            </span>
            <button class="btn btn-send" type="submit" >Send</button>
            @ViewBag.Message
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here is Email Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult SendEmail(EmailContent emailContent, List<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Email Sent Successfully!";
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.Project = new SelectList(db.employees, "employee_id", "name");
            ViewBag.Message = "Failed to Send Email, Please Try Again";
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
    }
}
```

Please Help i want return no view , modal still open.

Comment: Your submitting a form and redirecting to a new page! If you want to stay o the same page, then use ajax to submit your data.